# Why doesn't Visual Studio fire a warning at self-assignment (int foo = foo;)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, warnings

I was refactoring a term which appeared a bazilion times when by accident I produced a situation like in the code below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int foo = foo;

//By replacing with the following instruction we causes a compile error
//int foo(foo);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int bar = bar;
    std::cout << "Well this is awkward " << foo << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With different debug and release configurations the compiler is silent about `int foo = foo;`.

I fail to see a situation where this statement is not a bug waiting to happen. Shouldn't the Visual Studio compiler fire a warning?

I am not pretending this is an undefined behavior. I am saying that by default making an assignment from a variable to itself is likely to be the programmer mistake. Unless someone has a weird scheme around the use of the assignment operator.

Comment: Why "obviously"? `foo` has static storage and is thus zero-initialized.

Comment: It's legal.  Move it inside a function to see the diagnostic.

Comment: @UmNyobe can you give an example where this can cause a bug?

Comment: Weird, my Visual Studio (2010) fires a warning (C4700) WarningLevel = W3

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue (`i=i++`) is indeed undefined behavior, but it's mainly because the instruction contains two assignments to the same variable:

- The incrementing of `i` (`i++`), which is done at some point *after* the instruction `i++` returns `i`
- The assignment of `i`

The problem is that we can't really know if the assignment of `i` happens before or after incrementing, thus undefined behavior.

In your example, `foo=foo`, we have a read, followed by a write. Unambiguously, we will have to read the value before writing to it, so it's easy to define.

A side note is that if `operator=` is redefined, then `foo=foo` could do a lot of things that aren't simply a copy of foo into itself. C++ purposefully allows you to shoot yourself in the food in many different ways.  But in any case C++ compilers are not the gold standard of pro-activeness in warnings/errors.