# C++ warning to detect initialisation from self of reference fields

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-warnings

I had a bug caused by a bad copy constructor which initialised its field from itself:

```
Foo(const Foo& rhs)
  : bar(bar)      // error
{}
```

Obviously this should have been:

```
Foo(const Foo& rhs)
  : bar(rhs.bar)
{}
```

Is there a compiler diagnostic that would have detected this? Would this code ever potentially make sense?

`-Winit-self` doesn't seem to catch this.

**EDIT**

Thanks to [ForEveR's code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cf2f7fe5d98b9b1) that showed the warning *is* provided by GCC 4.9.2, I dug a little deeper to determine why I wasn't seeing one.

It turns out that it depends upon the type of the field being copied.

```
class A
{
public:
   A(const A&) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
private:
   int a;
   int* b;
   int& c;
};
```

This code only provides a warning about `a` (copy by value)  and `b` (by pointer), but **not** for `c` (by reference).

With this now known, is it still reasonable to expect GCC to identify initialisation of references from self as an issue?

Clang does identify all three of these as warnings, offering for `b`:

> reference 'b' is not yet bound to a value when used here

**EDIT** I opened an issue in GCC's bug tracker for this:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64667

Comment: @bolov: Only at namespace scope. They're fine at other scopes (provided the second character isn't an uppercase).

Comment: The construction is never right, since you would always be reading an uninitialized or otherwise "not yet alive" object.

Comment: @KerrekSB, in that case would it make sense to have a compiler diagnostic for this case?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: It does, and they do (see my answer).

Comment: [i reported something similar for assignment in msvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116684/why-doesnt-visual-studio-fire-a-warning-at-self-assignment-int-foo-foo)

Comment: It works for me, under MinGW 4.8.2.

Answer (score 6):

In gcc you can use flag 
`Winit-self` (at least on gcc v 4.8.2 flag catch this situation), or just `Wall`.
In clang it's enabled by default, via flag `Wuninitialized`.

Tried on gcc 4.9.2 [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cf2f7fe5d98b9b1). There is warning.

Comment: Tried this in GCC (as mentioned in the question). Doesn't work.

Comment: gcc `4.9.1` with `-Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Wuninitialized` shows no warnings whatsoever

Comment: Thanks for providing the example. It triggered me to do some more testing and I determined this only occurs for reference fields (see edit). Looks like it may be a bug in GCC.

Answer (score 3):

There are modern compilers that warn on this. For example, Clang says:

```
warning: field 'x' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    Foo(Foo const & rhs) : x(x) {}
```

The code:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(Foo const & rhs) : x(x) {}
    int x;
};
```

Comment: since the OP compiles with gcc and it looks like gcc doesn't warn on this due to a bug, it might be that compiling with clang is not an (optimal solution). Never used it, but wandered if clang static analyzer can be used in this case?

Comment: Turns out that GCC 4.9.2 skips this warning for initialisation of reference fields. It does warn for values and pointers, however.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine in GCC. Check your compiler installation. Use `-Winit_self`.

Tested code:

```
class Foo{
  int bar;
  public:
  Foo(const Foo& rhs)
   : bar(bar)      // error
  {}
};

int main()
{}
```

Compiler output:

```
main.cpp: In copy constructor 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)':
main.cpp:4:3: warning: 'Foo::bar' is initialized with itself [-Winit-self]
   Foo(const Foo& rhs)
   ^
```

If you're using a Makefile, you might want to check if it is not suppressing any warnings.

As per your comment, the best you can hope for to in this case is to make an assertion(And hope you get it right):

```
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Foo{
  public:
  int& bar;
  Foo(int& i)
   : bar(i)
  {}
  Foo(const Foo& rhs)
   : bar(bar)
  {
    assert(&bar == &rhs.bar);
  }
};

int main()
{
  int i;
  Foo a(i);
  Foo b(a);
}
```

That gives an assertion failure, when expected, at least for me. Can't tell if this is implementation defined, unfortunately.

Comment: Try making your `bar` field of type `int&`. I wasn't aware of this requirement when originally writing the question. See the edit.

Comment: Wow, that's nasty. And yes, probably a bug.

Comment: the best you can do is to post a bug report(witch you already did), and, for now, use an assertion to catch the error in runtime. See my edit.

Comment: The point is to warn about the the programmer's (compile-time) error. I can't see how an assertion (run-time) would help here unless if became habitual to add this, which I doubt anyone would realistically be convinced to make the required concerted effort.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm merely stating the fact that it's impossible to make this assertion statically, simply put. Personally, I would write a unit test simulating this behaviour, so as to not reintroduce the bug in the future. Let's hope GCC will fix this soon.